# How to capture packet using agent in JADE (Java Agent Development Framework)?

Tags: ids

I need to design an IDS using Mobile agent. Can anyone suggest how packet capture software is efficient in [JADE](http://jade.tilab.com/), how to match the captured packet for intrusion?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with JADE, but at a first glance it doesn't *look* like it supports packet capture. For that you will need a native binding to a packet capture library. In java, this would be [JPCap](http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/).

Once you have the packet sniffing working, you need to come up with a set of rules. The preferred method is to create a **whitelist**; write rules that describe *normal* traffic, with as little room for change as possible, and then log anything else.